# Meaning of 'signifier'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2016/jul/30/attachment-parenting-best-way-raise-child-or-maternal-masochism) paragraph five reads as follows: -

> Like the trend for “wellness” and clean eating, attachment parenting
>   posits that the modern world has corrupted what was once pure, through
>   scientific intervention. Rejecting modernity has become **the ultimate
>   aspirational signifier**, from fetishising cycling over driving to
>   praising farmers’ markets over supermarkets; after all, in order to
>   reject something, you not only need access to it, you have to have so
>   many options, you don’t even need it. It also has about it a touch of
>   anti-intellectualism, an increasingly popular stance in everything
>   from politics to nutrition.

The writer uses the word ' signifier' but based on my understanding of a 'signifier' , it usually means ' sound-image'.

For example, when I write the word ' dog ', it produces the inscription 'dog ', but also the concept of a dog: a four-legged canine creature. The first is thus called ' signifier' based on Saussure's understanding of a sign. But what does the word 'signifier' in this article  mean or imply in the article? Or can I replace the word 'signifier' with another word like 'objective' or 'goal'?

Answer (score 3):

The key part of the paragraph for this question I would say is this: -

...Rejecting modernity has become the ultimate aspirational signifier, from fetishising cycling over driving to praising farmers’ markets over supermarkets...

***Signifier*** ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signifier)):

> A symbol, sound, or image (as a word) that represents an underlying
>   concept or meaning

In this case the the 'reject[ion of] modernity' is signifying aspiration.

The signal here is a symbol, and that symbol is the rejection of modernity.

What is it signifying? In the context of the piece and this paragraph the second definition of aspirational here, appears to be the best match:-

***Aspirational*** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aspirational))

> Aimed at or appealing to people who want to attain a higher social
>   position or standard of living

The 'rejection of modernity' here is ***signifying*** that the person that is engaged in this act of rejection is trying to 'attain a higher social position or standard of living'.

Specifically here I would argue that both 'higher social position' and 'standard of living' apply. As there is a distinct air of aloofness in the way these individuals are characterised in the article.

Which would lend credence to the 'higher social position' motive: -

> "In order to reject something, you not only need access to it, you
>   have to have so many options, you don’t even need it. It also has
>   about it a touch of anti-intellectualism, an increasingly popular
>   stance in everything from politics to nutrition."

While the striving for an improved quality of life is also evident: -

> From fetishising cycling over driving to praising farmers’ markets
>   over supermarkets

In answer to your question, signifier would appear to be the best choice of word here.

The words 'goal' or 'objective' would not work, because the word 'signifier' is setting up a relationship between the 'rejection of modernity' and an 'aspirational approach to life'. That relationship element is lost if you simply say, the goal (or objective) is an 'aspirational life'.

I think the piece is fairly well written. But as an aid to comprehension you could convey the same ideas with slightly simpler vocabulary like this:

> Rejecting the modern life has become the ultimate indicator of an
>   aspirational approach to life.

Answer (score 2):

Saussure used 'signifier' in an extremely narrow linguistic sense, even making a stipulated technical meaning for it.

The usual meaning of 'signifier' is just [outward experiential sign in distinction to inner meaning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signifier).

In the passage you gave, riding a bicycle or driving a car are signifiers (outward signs) of different concepts of modernity.

Saussure's concepts, only a hundred and some years old, distinguished between meaning or mental concept and what suggested the meaning. a written or spoken word, a gesture, or a picture. Though most of his writing were about language and aural utterances, the concept applies as well to non-linguistic situations.